# Getting information about remote device in blackberry bluetooth

Tags: java, blackberry, bluetooth

I am developing a blackberry mobile app and I am using the javax.bluetooth api for using bluetooth in my application. I was wondering whether its possible to get the information about the remote device. I am able to fetch the name and address of the remote bluetooth deices but I also want to know the type of the device. I want to know whether the remote device is a Phone or PC. Is it possible to determine this in Blackberry OS 5?
I am using the following code to get the name and the address of the remote device.

```
System.out.println((i + 1) + ". "
                                + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress() + " ("
                                + remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(true) + ")");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get the type of the device. The device type can be found by using the `Device Class`. In `deviceDiscovered()` method of the `Discovery Agent` we get the `Remote Device` along with the `Device class`. We can use the `getMajorDeviceClass()` method of the Device Class to get the type of Device.
The type of Major Device Class is given in this [link](https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/baseband.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should use `DiscoveryAgent.searchServices()` method to retrieve this information:

public int searchServices(int[] attrSet,
                          UUID[] uuidSet,
                          RemoteDevice btDev,
                          DiscoveryListener listener)
                   throws BluetoothStateException

Take a look on javadoc for more info: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryAgent.html

Comment: What service should I search for? I mean what attrSet should be given? As far as I have looked into this wont give me the type of Device. I am interested to know whether the device is a phone or a PC.

Comment: I have a Blackberry OS 6 device and I do my testing on that. In that when I search for bluetooth devices, it immediately gives me the list of bluetooth devices and their type. Then gradually the name starts building because that process takes long. Is there some feature in Blackberry OS 6?